# Spring MVC weblogic ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, weblogic

I'm trying to setup a basic spring-mvc project with weblogic. I get this stacktrace

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:114)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:192)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:187)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:83)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1025)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:986)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:83)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:607)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:539)
```

I have no custom code, I used IntelliJ and Spring. Can you help me?

Comment: Your jar dependencies are not being exported to your weblogic, at least `spring-framework`'s ones. Review your packaging rules to see why dependencies are not being packaged with the application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `jar` dependencies are missing. You have to import them manually or in case of using Maven, add thee lines to your `pom.xml`, that assures all the dependencies.

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.3.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Then you can clean and rebuild your project. It should be ok.

Comment: I added it to `pom.xml` but I still get the same stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

In same cases this is due to a conflict within WebLogic internal libraries and your application, may be you should try to use this :

```
<prefer-application-packages>    
   <package-name>org.springframework.*</package-name>
</prefer-application-packages>
```

Comment: In which file? web.xml?

Comment: This piece of the script could be in the weblogic.xml, inside the container-descriptor tag.